# Find total number of uphill paths in Nordic square as a function of n.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let n be a positive integer. A Nordic square is an n×n board containing all the integers from 1 to $n^2$ so that each cell exactly contains one number .Two different cells are considered adjacent if they share a common side.Every cell that is adjacent only to cells containing larger numbers is called a valley.An uphill path is a sequence of one or more cells such that :

i) the first cell in the sequence is a valley,

ii) each subsequent cell in the sequence is adjacent to the previous cell, and

iii) the numbers written in the cells in the sequence are in increasing order.

Find as a function of n, the smallest possible total number of uphill paths in a Nordic square.This is from International Mathematics Olympiad 2022,everyone can try it out,I am also trying.

Comment: It is good that you give source of the question. However on this site you are expected to provide some of your own thoughts/work on it.

Comment: I have posted it here so that others can also discuss for their good in the community.I am also trying it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems like the IMO 2022 is still in progress. I feel like it is standard practice to keep questions closed until the end date. I might be wrong though so sorry if that is the case.

Comment: IMO 2022 has ended for the contestants yesterday, and the result is in progress.

Comment: @Tiger Fair enough, just making sure.

Comment: Some extra contest: This is 2022 IMO/6 -- the hardest problem on the contest. There is a solution on the AoPS thread for it: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2883218p25635163